# Looking for free Linux OS

Tags: linux

I would want to install a free Linux OS in my laptop. I am not a techie. I am looking for Linux OS which will have inbuilt features for Fn(Function) keys. Please suggest me if you know any particular Linux OS with these features.

Comment: superuser.com looks forward to this question :)

Comment: @duDE, no, they probably don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This OS have a laptop version. Easy to use, and supports the newest hardwares:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Thanks @Kovge. Do you know if it has features to support Fn Keys. or shall we need any 3rd party tool?

Comment: I have had never problems with FN keys , and using this os for years. 
who is the manufacturer of your laptop?

Comment: I have toshiba M115-S3094 laptop. It is 6 years old. Are you able to setup multiple displays? Are you able to increase/decrease the brightness of the screen?

Comment: Yes. Never had problem with this, i had compaq and asus laptops. 
I can say only. download the os, start as live disk, try it and if it seems to be good install then, if not, choose other os. I think the newest ubuntu supports a lot of hardwares.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many choices. Ubuntu is the defacto first distro, although I don't really care for it ever since they went to Unity and Gnome 3. I would rather use Mint with Cinnamon.

A good start is to look at something like Linux Watch http://distrowatch.com/ and see what distros sound good to you, then burn the live disk and check it out. If you like it you can then install it.